# Python modules for version 2.6 / 2.7

Tags: python, pygtk

I need to use two python versions on my Ubuntu system: 2.6.5 and 2.7.2 (for compatibility with some third-party projects).

For both of them, I need the PyGTK package.

I installed the latest version of this package, but strangely, only the 2.6 version identifies it; the 2.7 version cannot find it:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:/usr/lib$ python2.6 
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygtk
>>> print pygtk._get_available_versions()
{'2.0': '/usr/lib/gtk-2.0'}
>>> quit()

erelsgl@ubuntu:/usr/lib$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 16 2011, 09:51:01) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk
>>>
```

Comment: For what is worth, in my system I have: `/usr/share/pyshared/pygtk.pth` and `/usr/share/pyshared/pygtk.py` and both of them are linked in `/usr/lib/python2.X/dist-packages`. However, there's a different `.pyc` file for each python version (and I've used my OS package installer).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to download and install pyGTK separately for both versions. Don't use the OS package installer.

Download separate egg packages of pyGTK for both versions. Then run setup.py of each egg using the respective python interpreter. E.g.

`...../python26/python /download/pyGTK-2.6/setup.py install

...../python27/python /download/pyGTK-2.7/setup.pt install`

Comment: This sounds promising, but - where can I find an egg package for pyGTK? I didn't find any egg in their official site.

Comment: However they do have sources. Just decompress and run "python27/python download/pyGTK/setup.py build install"

Comment: erelsgl@ubuntu:~/pygtk-2.24.0$ sudo python setup.py build install********************************************************************
* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
********************************************************************

Comment: And going by the INSTALL file sends me to a seemingly endless path of broken dependencies... pygobject, gobject-introspection, and what else?

Answer (score 0):

if you just intend to use pygtk
then you can remove the python 2.7 from both the directories and link the lib/python 2.6 with lib/python

I faced the same problem while installing numpy, I solved it like this